# Keyboard Shortcut Ctrl+B and Ctrl+I in RMarkdown and RStudio

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

When writing reports in RMarkdown I realized that hitting `Ctrl+B` for **bold** or `Ctrl+I` for *italic* won't emphasize the text marked. Many other Markdown editors (for example the editor on StackOverflow) do this job.

For the moment I work with `Shift+*` after marking the `text` I want to show in bold which returns `*text*` which would be displayed in *italic*. However for making something **bold** I need to do this twice. And returning the action (removing the **) is not possible with this procedure.

Is there a hidden button somewhere in RStudio where I can turn this option on? Or is there some other solution to this problem like a package who does the job?

Comment: You can create an RStudio add-in and assign keyboard shortcuts to it, but your best option is going to be to file a support ticket with RStudio for a feature enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is installing the addin remedy `remotes::install_github("ThinkR-open/remedy")` and then to map your preferred key combination to the bold formatting offered by the addon.

So, it's a two-step process. First, install `remedy`, and then modify the keyboard shortcuts (Tools > Modify Keyboard Shortcuts...).

After installing `remedy`, there should be a 'bold' option for you in the shortcuts' list to make the binding.